# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (9,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to compare 2 numpy arrays

```
np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) == np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b1eabe8aba9f> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) == np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (9,)
```

I am using:

```
Windows 11
python 10
numpy 1.25
```

**Edit: This comparison was happening before numpy 1.25**

Comment: Hey @ChristophRackwitz earlier versions were supporting this comparison. Check with versions before 1.25

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.` so I would *not* say that it was "supported". the `==` operator always performs element-wise comparison. the result is an array. it always has been.

Comment: There is a difference btw warning and error. Now at 1.25 it throws Error earlier it was giving warning. Hope you understand the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the numpy document:

https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.25.0-notes.html#expired-deprecations

I found this:

Posting here if someone finds this useful:

> == and != warnings have been finalized. The == and != operators on arrays now always:

> raise errors that occur during comparisons such as when the arrays have incompatible shapes (np.array([1, 2]) == np.array([1, 2, 3])).

---

From `numpy 1.25` onwards

**`==` and `!=` will always raise error in array comparison if the shapes are incompatible.**

So, in a nutshell we cannot use `==` to compare arrays of different lengths.

To compare two arrays of different sizes, you could use [`numpy.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html)

```py
>>> np.array_equal(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
False
```